# How to specify max-height = min(30em, window.height * 75%) in CSS?

Tags: css

I have a div dialog, I want to limit its height no more then 30 lines of text, but also won't overflow the window. Can I?

Well, I guess I can't calculate min value in CSS...

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to style it with the following rules:

```
.dialog {
  height:75%;
  min-height:30em;
}
```

This will cause it to be 75% of its parent (the window), unless it would cause it to be greater than 30em, in which case it will not grow.

There's a bit more to it than that, so I've made a jsfiddle to show. Resize the window to see it work. http://jsfiddle.net/mbxtr/hvWZW/